# Bittorrent Adding of peer

Tags: c++, bittorrent

I have written a bittorrent program, my bittorrent speed for adding of peer is working. However the peer are added to the chord at a slow speed. How can i speed them up? I have attached part of my code. Thank you for the help

```
vector<int> vectorNode;
pair<int,int> pnNode ;
int prev;
int next;

pnNode = getPreviousNextNode(id);
prev = pnNode.first;
next = pnNode.second;

map<int, Node>::iterator nextNode ;

nextNode = Node_List.find(next);

if(prev > id)
{
    while(++prev < size - 1)
    {
        vectorNode.push_back(prev);
        prev = 0;
    }
    while(++prev < id)
    {
        vectorNode.push_back(prev);
    }
}

for(map<int, string>::iterator t = nextNode->second.data.begin(); t != nextNode->second.data.end(); ++t)
{
    for(vector<int>::iterator tmp = vectorNode.begin(); tmp != vectorNode.end(); ++tmp)
    {
        if(*tmp == t->first)
        {
            nextNode->second.Insert(t->second, *this);
            nextNode->second.data.erase(t);
        }
    }
}
```

My program will intialise a chord and start adding peer from peer 1 to 1000. Then it will list out the peer.
Example of adding peer 1 to 5 and my program will output
0-1-2-3-4-5
however the problem i am facing is that the time tke to compute is too slow?
i hope the description will be useful.
Thank you for taking time to read.

Comment: `while(++prev < size - 1)
    {
        vectorNode.push_back(prev);
        prev = 0;
    }`looks like an endless loop to me

Comment: There's nothing worng, i have successfully added 1000 peers. However the time taken is very long. I want to shorten it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Then you are probably never entering the loop at all - I can guarantee you that once you enter it, you will never leave it (assuming `size` is bigger than 1). As far ad performance is concerned I'd be happy to help, once you provide an [mcve](/help/mcve)  that  ideally includes some sort of benchmark  that demonstrates the Problem.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I dont quite get what is mcve.(The code i listed out should be Minimal???) My program can add 100 peer in a minute. I want to make it complete the process in 10 second. How should i do that? The coding i posted is the method to add peers.

Comment: In this case ***"complete"*** and ***"verifiable"*** would be the more important parts. What is `id`, `Node` and `Node_List`? How many entries does the list have? Have you turned compiler optimizations on? what exactly takes a minute? Unless `Insert`is a very costly operation or the data structures contain millions of entries, I would have expected this to take a few milliseconds at most. Is there IO involved somewhere?

Comment: hi, actually im doing the dht part for bittorrent, the id means the peer id.

Comment: Sorry I forget to add on these information. it will read in string from text file, the number of peer is equivalent to the line in text file. 1000 line means 1000 peer and the node is use to store these string data. Yes insert is costly and the bottle neck is the way my code add peer. For my peer to complete adding from peer 0 to peer 99, the time take is 70 seconds.The timing is too slow as it should be like milliseconds. Thanks for your help,have a nice day